# Biblatex: Citing "full author" after short author was cited

Tags: biblatex

Recently I learned how to cite the shortauthor instead of a long name of the corporate author. However, there are some occasions that I need to cite the full name again, such as in notes of tables or figures that need to provide descriptions that are independent from the rest of the text. As one can see, however, only the shortauthor was cited when I tried to cite its author only.

How can I cite the "full author" again even after the shortauthor was cited?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo1.bib}
@Book{cite1,
  author = {{Longname May-be-cited-in-full Sometimes Corporation}},
  title     = {On a Work Cited by Everyone},
  publisher = {Long City: Longname},
  year      = {2017},
  shortauthor = {LMSC},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,texencoding=utf8,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa} 
\bibliography{foo1}
\begin{document}

The work is already cited at least once with the full author name \parencite{cite1}. After that, when it is cited again, the \emph{shortauthor} field is used \parencite{cite1}.

In some stand-alone figure, I would also mention the full name of the author, such as this\\

 ``Adapted from \citetitle{cite1}, by  \citeauthor{cite1}, \citeyear{cite1}.'' \\

 As one can see, however, only the shortauthor was cited.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\citeresetapa\citereset
```

to reset citation tracking before `\citeauthor`.

Comment: Thank you and it works! Just a follow up question: after the reset command, the citation of author shows "Longname May-be-cited-in-full Sometimes Corporation [LMSC]”. Is there a way to suppress the [LMSC] abbreviation?

Comment: @KaiChungTam That is that standard way it shows. I would not change that. There is no easy fix to do this, but it could be done with some changes to the code, do you really need this?